# Docker-compose volume not storing files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm having trouble demonstrating that data I generate on a shared volume is persistent, and I can't figure out why. I have a very simple docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

# Define network
networks:
    sorcernet:
        name: sorcer_net

# Define services
services:
    preclean:
        container_name: cleaner
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DEESfile
        image: dees
        networks:
            - sorcernet
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/usr/share/appdata
        #command: python run dees.py

    process:
        container_name: processor
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: OASISfile
        image: oasis
        networks:
            - sorcernet
        volumes:
            - pgdata:/usr/share/appdata

volumes:
    pgdata:
        name: pgdata
```

Running the docker-compose file to keep the containers running in the background:

```
vscode ➜ /com.docker.devenvironments.code $ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Network sorcer_net   Created
 ⠿ Volume "pgdata"      Created
 ⠿ Container processor  Started
 ⠿ Container cleaner    Started
```

Both images are running:

```
vscode ➜ /com.docker.devenvironments.code $ docker image ls
REPOSITORY      TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
oasis          latest      e2399b9954c8    9 seconds ago   1.09GB
dees           latest      af09040befd5   31 seconds ago   1.08GB
```

and the volume shows up as expected:

````
vscode ➜ /com.docker.devenvironments.code $ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     pgdata```
````

Running the docker container, I navigate to the volume folder. There's nothing in the folder -- this is expected.

```
vscode ➜ /com.docker.devenvironments.code $ docker run -it oasis
[root@049dac037802 opt]# cd /usr/share/appdata/
[root@049dac037802 appdata]# ls
[root@049dac037802 appdata]#
```

Since there's nothing in the folder, I create a file in called "dog.txt" and recheck the folder contents. The file is there. I exit the container.

```
[root@049dac037802 appdata]# touch dog.txt
[root@049dac037802 appdata]# ls
dog.txt
[root@049dac037802 appdata]# exit
exit
```

To check the persistence of the data, I re-run the container, but nothing is written to the volume.

```
vscode ➜ /com.docker.devenvironments.code $ docker run -it oasis
[root@1787d76a54b9 opt]# cd /usr/share/appdata/
[root@1787d76a54b9 appdata]# ls
[root@1787d76a54b9 appdata]#
```

What gives? I've tried defining the volume as persistent, and I know each of the images have a folder location at `/usr/share/appdata`.

Comment: `docker run` doesn't know anything about the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Do you mean `docker-compose run process /bin/sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the persistence of the data in the containers defined in your docker compose, the `--volumes-from` flag is the way to go

When you run

```
docker run -it oasis
```

This newly created container shares the same image, but it doesn't know anything about the volumes defined.

In order to link the volume to the new container run this

```
docker run -it --volumes-from $CONTAINER_NAME_CREATED_FROM_COMPOSE oasis
```

Now this container shares the volume `pgdata`.

You can go ahead and create files at `/usr/share/appdata` and validate their persistence